# Prove that $ a^4b^4+ a^4c^4+b^4c^4\le3$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=3$. Prove that 
>   $$ a^4b^4+ a^4c^4+b^4c^4\le3$$

**My attempts:**

1) $$ a^4b^4+ a^4c^4+b^4c^4\le \frac{(a^4+b^4)^2}{4}+\frac{(c^4+b^4)^2}{4}+\frac{(a^4+c^4)^2}{4}$$

2) $$a^4b^4+ a^4c^4+b^4c^4\le3=a^3+b^3+c^3$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM and Schur we obtain 
$$\sum_{cyc}a^4b^4=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}(3ab)a^3b^3\leq\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}(1+a^3+b^3)a^3b^3=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^3+a^6b^3+a^6c^3)=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}a^3\sum_{cyc}a^3b^3+\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}(a^6b^3+a^6c^3)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}(4a^6b^3+4a^6c^3+a^3b^3c^3)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\left(\sum_{cyc}(a^9+3a^6b^3+3a^6c^3+2a^2b^2c^2)-\sum_{cyc}(a^9-a^6b^3-a^6c^3+a^3b^3c^3)\right)\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}(a^9+3a^6b^3+3a^6c^3+2a^2b^2c^2)=\frac{1}{9}(a^3+b^3+c^3)^3=3.$$